# Run maths again with new textfield input Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I make my maths run again in this code?

I have my text fields updating when theres no maths involved. I imagine it's something in the order of my code.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="center">
  <h2>Book Counter</h2>
    <form>
        <label><p>Book Name: </p></label>
        <input name="booktitle" id="booktitle" type="text">
        <label><p>Total Pages: </p></label>
        <input name="total-pages" id="total-pages" type="text">
        <label><p>Current Page: </p></label>
        <input name="pages" id="pages" type="text">
        <button id="my-btn" type="button">SUBMIT</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="info">
    <h2>Book Info</h2>
    <div id="bookName"></div>
    <div id="totalPages"></div>
    <div id="pagesLeft"></div>
    <p>Pages Remaining.</p>
    <div id="percentageLeft"></div>
    <p>Remaining.</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function() {


// pull value from text field and set to object



 document.getElementById("my-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
      book.name = document.getElementById('booktitle').value;
      bookName.textContent = book.name;

      book.totalPages = document.getElementById('total-pages').value;
      totalPages.textContent = 'Total Pages: ' + book.totalPages;

      book.pages = document.getElementById('pages').value;
      book.pages.textContent = book.pages;
  });

// Create book object

var book =  {

name: 'Tom & Jerry',
totalPages: 622,
pages: 162,
pagesLeft: function() {
  var total = this.totalPages - this.pages;
  return total;
},
percentageLeft: function() {
  var totalPercentage = this.pagesLeft()/this.totalPages * 100
  return Math.round(totalPercentage);
}
};


// write out book name and pages info

var bookName, totalPages, pagesLeft, percentageLeft; //declares variables

bookName = document.getElementById('bookName'); // gets elements from document
totalPages = document.getElementById('totalPages');
pagesLeft = document.getElementById('pagesLeft');
percentageLeft = document.getElementById('percentageLeft');


bookName.textContent = book.name; // write to document
totalPages.textContent = 'Total Pages: ' + book.totalPages;
pagesLeft.textContent =  book.pagesLeft();
percentageLeft.textContent =  book.percentageLeft() + '%';

}());
```

I've added the codepen too. http://codepen.io/Middi/pen/pRGOVW

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery does not have a digest loop so functions will not be updated. You need to move this into your on click event:

```
pagesLeft.textContent =  book.pagesLeft();
percentageLeft.textContent =  book.percentageLeft() + '%';
```

For better code consistency you might want to consider moving all of the display setter lines into the click event.